# How do you describe this body position?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, image-identification

[image]

My best guess is "man putting his hand on his head" but I know there's something less gothic than that.

Comment: I understand from your comments that you are looking for something like an *alt* attribute textual description for screen readers. Depending on the context . . . *Man resting his head on his palm*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is resting his head in his hand.

From The J. Paul Getty Museum

[Woman resting her head in her hand](http://www.getty.edu/art/collection/objects/212317/unknown-maker-woman-resting-her-head-in-her-hand-about-1915-1931/)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps resting his head *on* his hand?

Comment: @RichardKayser - "... ***On***  his hand," would actually infer that he was resting on the back of his hand (rather than the palm).

Answer (score 1):

That's called *propping*.

> **Prop (verb):** 
>   [with object and adverbial of place] Support or keep in position.
>
> Example: She propped her chin in the palm of her right hand.

— [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/prop)

In your picture, he has propped up his head on his hand.

[image]

[Google](https://images.app.goo.gl/bGvf12KmsMKP61Mv6)

Comment: Can I / Is it ok to say : "he has propped up the right corner of his forehead on his right hand" ?

Comment: because I have to describe the picture for blind people :-)

Comment: Broadly you can not say "He has propped up the right corner of his forehead on his right hand" 

"… propping/resting…" works but few if any native speakers would use "propping up" in a context like that.

It's almost as unlikely anyone would say "He has propped (up) the right corner of his forehead on his right hand" because that's (a little) like saying "He has walked along the road, repeatedly moving one knee past the other." Not actually wrong just, usually, pointless.

The rare cases where it might work belong in SE English Language Learners, or somewhere dealing with writing.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, I have to describe the picutre for blind native english speakers, as why I was asking it here.